# Replacing question mark with exclamation mark and vice versa

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, character

I need to write a function that receives a sentence string and a true/false 'shouting' argument. It should return the string, replacing any question marks with exclamation marks and vice versa. If 'shouting' is true, all letters should be in uppercase.

```
function changeIntonation(str, isShouting) {
let myString = '';
let regExcl = /\!/;
let regQmark = /\?/;

let qMarkStr = str.replace(regQmark, '!');
let finalStr = qMarkStr.replace(regExcl, '?');

let newArr = finalStr.split('');

if(isShouting === true) {
  let upperCaseArr = newArr.map(function(char){
    return char.toUpperCase();
  })
  myString = upperCaseArr.join('');
}
return myString;
```

}

My code works when I try to convert **Hey! How are you?** to **HEY?HOW ARE YOU!**, but when I test **Hey? How are you!** it just makes it upper case and the exclamation and question mark remain unchanged.
Also **!?**  to **?!** fails.
Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Think about what `qMarkStr` is set to when running your code in your failed example.

Comment: You are switching question to explanation then explanation back to question...You are changing it then you are changing it right back. You will need a little logic to do that conversion.

Comment: If it has already been replaced don't replace it again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you try to replace `!` with `?` and **then** replace `?` with `!`, you risk replacing, by mistake, original `!` and `?` that existed.

To work around that, you have to replace `!` and `?` in one command, like ([using a function argument on `String#replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)):

```
let finalStr = str.replace(/[!?]/g, function(c) { return c === '?' ? '!' : '?'; });
```

Also you don't need to call `.toUpperCase()` on each char, you can use it on the string:

```js
function changeIntonation(str, isShouting) {
  let finalStr = str.replace(/[!?]/g, function(c) { return c === '?' ? '!' : '?'; });

  if (isShouting === true) {
    return finalStr.toUpperCase();
  } else {
    return finalStr;
  }
}
console.log(changeIntonation("Hey! How are you?", true));
console.log(changeIntonation("Hey! How are you?", false));
console.log(changeIntonation("Hey? How are you!", true));
console.log(changeIntonation("Hey? How are you!", false));
```

Comment: Nice answer! IMO If you're going to use a ternary statement for replacement you might as well use it for isShouting too! :)

Comment: @zfrisch agreed! I probably would have done it if the code was mine. I didn't this time because I usually try to change the code as little as possible from the original snippet of the question. Sometimes the OP have a hard time figuring out what changed and what didn't.

Comment: Ah, I understand now! Thanks for the clarification as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @acdcjunior, who answered just before me and I didn't notice he already answered! My code looks like his, but is a little bit more compact.

```
function changeIntonation(str, isShouting) {
    str = str.replace(/\?|\!/g, function(match) {
        return match == "?" ? "!" : "?";
    });
    return isShouting ? str.toUpperCase() : str;
}
```

First of all I noticed you're making single characters upper-case to then join them all in a whole string. Why? I just made the whole string directly upper-case.
Then I understood the problem is that when you replace question marks with exclamation marks both those before were question and exclamation marks now are only exclamation marks, so if you try replacing exclamation marks with question ones, you'll replace them all.
So I choosed to replace with a callback both question and exclamations marks and check in the callback if the occurrence is the one or the other to replace correctly.